# Какой язык/библиотеку лучше использовать при создании конкретного тг бота?

Tags: python, php, node.js, telegram, aiogram

Всем привет, пару дней копаюсь и никак не могу определиться в языке/библиотеке/фреймворке который мне лучше использовать при создании телеграмм бота с конкретными задачами, а именно -
принятие и что более важное отправка данных с телеграмм бота на сайт(ы) и ихняя обработка. Сам по себе фронтендер по этому не сильно силён в этом. Из вариантов которые сразу приходят на ум - php и python а именно aiogram, но как выше сказано не силён в этом и так и не разобрался вообще ли реализуемо это с aiogram. Буду рад вашим подсказам и аргументации почему, лучшим на ваш взгляд алгоритмом действий. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для создания телеграмм бота, который должен взаимодействовать с веб-сайтом, вам нужно использовать язык программирования и библиотеки, которые позволят вам легко отправлять и принимать данные через HTTP протокол.

Язык программирования Python и фреймворк **aiogram** - это хороший выбор для создания телеграмм бота, поскольку **aiogram** обеспечивает легкую интеграцию с Telegram API, а Python имеет широкие возможности для работы с сетевыми запросами и обработкой данных.

Для отправки данных на веб-сайт вы можете использовать Python библиотеки, такие как **requests** или **urllib**, которые предоставляют простой и удобный API для отправки HTTP запросов на веб-сайт. Для обработки данных, которые вы получаете от веб-сайта, вы можете использовать библиотеки для парсинга данных, такие как **BeautifulSoup** или **lxml**.

Важно также убедиться, что веб-сайт, на который вы отправляете данные, предоставляет соответствующий API или механизм для приема и обработки данных. Некоторые веб-сайты могут требовать аутентификации или ключа API для доступа к их функционалу.

В общем, на основе ваших требований я бы порекомендовал использовать **aiogram** для создания телеграмм бота, а также **requests** и **BeautifulSoup** для отправки данных на веб-сайт и их обработки. Также не забывайте изучать документацию Telegram API и API веб-сайта, на который вы собираетесь отправлять данные.

Answer (score 0):

Пишите на том, на чем вам комфортнее/больше нравится. Если фронтендер, то знаете JS, следовательно, для вас проще всего будет начать на Node.JS. Есть хорошие библиотеки для всех предложенных вами языков.

- На node - https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api
- На PHP - https://github.com/westacks/telebot
- На Python - https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI